# Long running scheduled tasks in .net core and aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, .net-core, scheduled-tasks

I was wondering what would be the recommended way to host a long running scheduled task in AWS.

Currently we have an EC2 instance (windows) in charge of triggering our app every few hours. This task will take between 1-3 hours depending on the number of items to process.

- Lambda does not seem to be appropriate since my task is too long
- Found this topic about Hangfire [Scheduled Jobs in .NET Core 2 Web app hosted in AWS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46321059/scheduled-jobs-in-net-core-2-web-app-hosted-in-aws). Seems good but outside of AWS.

Any suggestions?

Thx
Seb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend AWS Step Functions. Very easy to implement. Part of the AWS Serverless Platform.

[AWS Step Functions](https://aws.amazon.com/step-functions/)

> AWS Step Functions makes it easy to coordinate the components of
>   distributed applications and microservices using visual workflows.
>   Building applications from individual components that each perform a
>   discrete function lets you scale and change applications quickly. Step
>   Functions is a reliable way to coordinate components and step through
>   the functions of your application. Step Functions provides a graphical
>   console to arrange and visualize the components of your application as
>   a series of steps. This makes it simple to build and run multistep
>   applications. Step Functions automatically triggers and tracks each
>   step, and retries when there are errors, so your application executes
>   in order and as expected. Step Functions logs the state of each step,
>   so when things do go wrong, you can diagnose and debug problems
>   quickly. You can change and add steps without even writing code, so
>   you can easily evolve your application and innovate faster.

Comment: Use Activities to synchronize between Step Functions & EC2.

Answer (score 1):

[Using AWS Lambda with Scheduled Events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-scheduled-events.html) would let you create an AWS Lambda that will respond to a scheduled event. This Lambda could then trigger your app. Your app doesn't need to be in a Lambda itself.